# C file handling query

Tags: c, string, file

So I have a program that takes user input and compares it to a specific line in a file, however the final line will always be credited as incorrect, so can someone solve this for me?, thanks.

File content (just a list of random words)

```
Baby
Milk
Car
Face
Library
Disc
Lollipop
Suck
Food
Pig
```

(libraries are stdio,conio and string)

```
char text[100], blank[100];
int c = 0, d = 0;

void space(void);

int main()
{
    int loop = 0;
    char str[512];
    char string[512];
    int line = 1;
    int dis = 1;
    int score = 0;
    char text[64];

    FILE *fd;

    fd = fopen("Student Usernames.txt", "r");   // Should be test

    if (fd == NULL)
    {
        printf("Failed to open file\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    do
    {
        printf("Enter the string: ");
        gets(text);

        while (text[c] != '\0')
        {
            if (!(text[c] == ' ' && text[c] == ' '))
            {
                string[d] = text[c];
                d++;
            }
            c++;
        }

 string[d] = '\0';
 printf("Text after removing blanks\n%s\n", string);

 getch();

for(loop = 0;loop<line;++loop)
{
    fgets(str, sizeof(str), fd);
}
printf("\nLine %d: %s\n", dis, str);
dis=dis+1;
str[strlen(str)-1] = '\0';
if(strcmp(string,str) == 0 )
 {
 printf("Match\n");
 score=score+2;
 }
     else
     {
     printf("Nope\n");
     score=score+1;
     }
 getch();
 c=0;
 d=0;
}
while(!feof(fd));
printf("Score: %d",score);
getch();
}
```

For any input on the last line, the output will always be incorrect, I believe this is something to do with the for loop not turning it into the next variable, but seeing as the <= notation makes this program worse, I really just need a simple fix for the program thanks.

Comment: `!(text[c] == ' ' && text[c] == ' ')` is the same as just `text[c] != ' '`.

Comment: "*libraries are ...*" should read "*headers are ...*".

Comment: The code seems incomplete, e.g. there is no `while` for the `do`.

Answer (score 0):

Some observations:

You must never use `gets` (it is not even in the C11 standard anymore). Instead of `gets(text)` use `fgets(text, sizeof(text), stdin)` – this way a long input will not overflow the `text` array.

There will be stuff printed at the end because you don't check the return value of either the `gets` or the `fgets`, so when end of file occurs for either the file or for user input the rest of that iteration still runs. `fgets` returns `NULL` if it didn't read anything – check for that instead of using `feof`.

You remove newlines from the file input but not from the user input, so the comparison will always fail when you switch from `gets` to `fgets` (which doesn't strip linefeeds). The second (otherwise pointless) comparison of `text[c]` against `' '` should be against `'\n'`.

**edit**: Also, in case the last line of your file does not end in a linefeed, the comparison will fail on the last line because you don't check if the last character is a linefeed before you remove it.

The `for (loop = 0; loop < line; ++loop)` -loop is pointless because `line` is always 1, so the body is only executed once.

You have unnecessarily global variables which the program hard to follow. And, for instance, your local `text[64]` overshadows the global `text[100]`, so if you think you are modifying the global buffer, you are not. If your code is complete, none of the variables should be global.

The function `getch()` is non-standard. There is no easy direct replacement, so you may just accept that you are not writing portable code, but it's something to be aware of.

Comment: So what should I do with the for loop?, change line to EOF?

Comment: @user3344560 I don't know what your point with the loop is supposed to be, but if the current behaviour is correct you can either do nothing (leaving a pointless loop in bad style), or remove the loop but not the `fgets` inside.

Comment: @user3344560 In light of your new questions about essentially the same code, please re-read this answer. I also added an edit that may help.